# How to convert a matrix to a bipartite graph with weights

Tags: java, r, algorithm, matrix, graph

My matrix is

```
   3 4 1 2 2  
   0 1 2 3 1  
   0 5 5 1 3  
   2 2 1 0 5  
   1 4 2 1 3
```

I am tasked with finding an optimal job assignment scheme based on this matrix. The working efficiency w (*ij* ) of the i-th worker doing the j-th job is described by the matrix above. I have two questions:

1) Can I turn this matrix into a bipartite graph neatly using code?
2) Is this an example where the Hungarian algorithm should be used?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in Java or R or it doesn't matter?

Comment: either one, there are a lot of useful packages in R when it comes to stuff like this so R might be easier but either one

Comment: What does Java have to do with this question?

Comment: I tagged Java and R as possible coding languages for this to be done in

Comment: I guess you can represent the bupartite graph using w, where w[i][j] > 0 iff  there is an edge from node i on the left to node j on the right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Petar already mentioned, the matrix w represents a bipartite graph. For each row you have a node in the first set, and for each column you have a node in the second set. Now each each entry w[i][j] represents an edge (with weight w[i][j]) between node i and node j.

Optimal job assignment (or maximum bipartite matching) is exactly the task that the hungarian algorithm solves. You actually do not need to convert the matrix in a graph structure as HA usually directly operates on matrices.